# How to let Cypress contains return boolean instead of failing the test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am testing a virtual dropdown list, my code is like this:

```
    while (!cy.contains('.ant-select-item',/^Cypress$/)) {
      cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown').trigger('wheel', {deltaX:0,deltaY:100});
    }
```

It keeps wheeling down until finds a specific element. However, this code does not work, when `contains` does not find the specific element, it fails the test instead of return false.
How to make the `while` loop work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery, `Cypress.$` instead.

```js
while (!Cypress.$('.ant-select-item:contains('Cypress').length) {
  cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown').trigger('wheel', {deltaX:0,deltaY:100});
}
```

One thing - `:contains()` will match partially, so this is no good if more than one item has the string.

Long version - `Cypress.$('.ant-select-item:contains('Cypress')` gets a list of matching elements. If none found, it does not fail but the length of the list is 0. Since `0` is falsy, the loop continues.

The loop idea is only good if the dropdown does actually contain the value somewhere, otherwise it spins forever.

Comment: your code doesn't work, the browser stuck. I guess it may because the page does not re-render after trigger wheel.

Comment: problem solved. I use async() and await Cypress.$(...) and await cy.get(...).trigger(...).

Answer (score 0):

While loops generally don't work with Cypress, it would be safer to use a repeating (recursive) function

```js
function findItem(item, loop = 0) {

  if (loop === 10) throw 'Too many attempts'

  cy.get('.ant-select-item')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(textsOfCurrentList => {
      if (!textsOfCurrentList.contains(item)) {
        // wheel down and try next
        cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown').trigger('wheel', {deltaX:0,deltaY:100})
        findItem(item, ++loop)  
      } else {
        return
      }
    })
})

findItem('Cypress')
```

Or with package [cypress-recurse](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse)

```js
recurse(
  () => cy.get('.ant-select-item').invoke('text'),
  (textsOfCurrentList) => {
    const found = textsOfCurrentList.contains(item)
    if (!found) {
      cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown').trigger('wheel', {deltaX:0,deltaY:100})
    }
    return found  // true means finish, false means repeat
  },
  {
    log: true,
    limit: 10, // max number of iterations
    timeout: 30000, // time limit in ms
  },
)
```

---

A good background info [avoid-while-loops-in-cypress](https://github.com/bahmutov/avoid-while-loops-in-cypress)